# Does Android Device Manager Work if the phone was reset?

Tags: sony-xperia

For this scenario let's assume the following:

> The phone is stolen and locked. The thief does not know the lock combination and cannot determine it.
>   There is an external SD slot.
>   The thief might already reseted my phone

In case it matters, the phone is a Sony Xperia z2

Comment: A factory reset from Recovery Mode will remove/unlink Android Device Manager, but (since Android 5.0) it will require your Google account password on first boot so the phone won't be usable.

Answer (score 0):

No, Android Device Manager will not work. It is so, as it does not have the data and information of its setting and accounts. But all of your data will not get in hand of thief.

Did you report it stolen with your carrier? They could report the ESN / IMEI as stolen so at the very least the thief probably wouldn't be able to sell it.

Comment: @LawleyGraceffa: that is a separate question and such category of questions are discouraged (asking them in comments, that is) since comments are primarily meant for suggestions and clarifications on the same topic. As for your question. try searching our site. The question already exist and has multiple answers.

Comment: Where should I report it?

Comment: First to police then to your network carrier.